# How can I manually compile something inside Eclipse?

Tags: compilation, javac, java

*One way of doing seemed to be to use the java.lang.Compiler*

I tried to use the java.lang.Compiler inside Eclipse anddid not understand the `Object any` parameters for the methods of that class? And putting in a class did not seem to work either.

```
Compiler.command(any) // what is meant by any? What are valid objects to put there?
Compiler.compileClass(clazz) // Nothing happens when I out a class in there?
Compiler.compileClasses(string) // hm?
```

How to can I print a hello message with a Compiler inside Eclipse...?

Comment: Why do you want to print smth using Compiler class? This class has nothing to do with printing. Probably, add more details or describe your issue more clear, so somebody can help you.

Comment: The printing is just to see wether or not it is working

Answer (score 0):

**Reading the documentation** is a very important skill you need to learn.

Whenever you come across a class or a method that you don't know the functionality of, simply look at the documentation first.

Here is the docs for `java.lang.Compiler`: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Compiler.html

This is the first sentence of the document:

> The Compiler class is provided to support Java-to-native-code compilers and related services. By design, the Compiler class **does nothing**; it serves as a placeholder for a JIT compiler implementation.

So, the answer to your question is, it does nothing. According to the documentation, it does nothing. It is used to start up the Java compiler when the JVM starts. You are not meant to use this.

Comment: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/lang/compiler_compileclasses.htm Why would it be a turtorial for something that cannot be used. Yes I read that documentation to start with. I am new to compilers so I did not know what the JIT compiler was

Comment: You _can_ use it, but you are not meant to use it, and it is not really useful for anything. I am not really familiar with TutorialsPoint but I think it will give an "example" for everything, just by looking at it. @lelelo

Comment: If I understand correctly eclipse is its own compiler - so why would it use javac (is that the `java.lang.Compiler` ?) to start a JIT compiler... and then start itself?

Comment: `java.lang.Compiler` is not `javac`. it's just an abstraction of the actual compiler used.

Comment: Great thanks. So I take it what is meant in the documention is that you should not meddle with the currently used compiler. You might wonder why it is even there then?

Comment: @lelelo It is there for the JVM to use.

Comment: It doesn't actually compile anything on its own, but it tells the JVM what compiler to use.

Comment: It would be great if you could be so kind and edit your answer to maybe provide the info about how the java.lang.Compiler is the actual compiler used etc.

Comment: And what I meant with "why is it even there?", was for me - a developer (Why can I access it?) The jvm does not need the documentation. And for some reason those 3 methods are declared as public...?